# CheckBox en DataGridView: no me marca el checkbox hasta dar un clic en otra fila

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, datagridview

Para ser más exacto, sí se marca el CheckBox, pero al momento de querer obtener la cuenta de los que están marcados, solo obtengo los primeros 4: el último siempre lo ignora, a menos que dé un clic en otra fila. Es decir, el último CheckBox que marco no se pone en True, hasta que deje de seleccionarlo o cambie de fila, parecido al Evento Leave de un TextBox, que se ejecuta hasta que sales del Textbox.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto? Al DataGridView y sus columnas los edito desde este panel.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el **evento CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged** pon este código:

```
if (datagrid.IsCurrentCellDirty)
{
   datagrid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

Este evento suele ocurrir cuando se ha editado una celda pero el cambio no se ha confirmado en la caché de datos, o cuando se cancela una operación de edición.

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias.